How to plot 2D with contourf in 3D projection of matplotlib.pyplot?
I want to plot a kind of torus in such a way:
def flux2cart(RHO, PHI, THETA):
    XX = (R0 + DEL0*(1.0-RHO**2) + RHO*A0*       np.cos(THETA) - RHO*A0*DELTA*np.sin(THETA)**2)*np.cos(PHI)        
    YY = (R0 + DEL0*(1.0-RHO**2) + RHO*A0*       np.cos(THETA) - RHO*A0*DELTA*np.sin(THETA)**2)*np.sin(PHI)
    ZZ = (Z0 + KSI0*(1.0-RHO**2) + RHO*A0*LAMBDA*np.sin(THETA) + RHO*A0*GAMMA*np.cos(THETA)**2)
    return XX, YY, ZZ

where R0, Z0, A0, DEL0, KSI0, LAMBDA, DELTA and GAMMA are constants, PHI and THETA are toroidal and poloidal angles and RHO is a kind of radius, but normalized (0 on axis, 1 on surface).
surface of the torus between 0<φ<2π/3 and two vertical cross-section colored as a function of RHO:
VAL = (1- RHO**2)**(3/2) for example.
Plotting surface is easy:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"}, figsize = (12, 10))
rho   = 1.
phi   = np.linspace(phi0, phi1, 101)
theta = np.linspace(0., 2.*np.pi, 101)
PHI, THETA = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)
XX, YY, ZZ = flux2cart(1., PHI, THETA)

But how to plot contour distribution VAL(RHO, 0., THETA) and VAL(RHO, 2π/3, THETA), where RHO = np.linspace(0., 1., 101), on the same figure I have no idea...
I've tried
ax.contourf(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2), z, val, levels=25, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

but that is not (1st picture), what I want (2nd picture)

I decided to make something like “stubs” at the ends of the torus, which I depicted as a surface plot:
cmap = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=val.min(), vmax=val.max()), cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=cmap.to_rgba(val), shade=False)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
